# Capturing Push Notifications in ios6

Tags: ios, sms, jailbreak

I am working on an extension for jailbroken ios6 devices that requires the capture of incoming SMS messages/other messaging apps. Is there a library or even a way of doing something like this?

Example from where I got inspiration is the GV SMS extension.
https://github.com/mrzzheng/GVExtensions

Comment: What are you asking about?  Push Notifications are a different thing than SMS messages.

Comment: I am trying to capture incoming google voice messages on my phone, I can't imagine any other way of getting them other than through its use of push notifications.